# Error function definition in neural networks

Tags: neural-network

So I’ve been doing this nano degree and i have this doubt that to calculate error , the Function need to have a predicted output and a true output , what I can’t understand is that how does the error function gets the true output? How does it knows what the true output would be? How does this thing works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to train your network. The way you are referring to is called back propagation. The idea is that you have a pre-existing dataset that consists of sample inputs and known outputs. Then you feed the network your samples, calculate an error using the expected outputs and actual outputs and adjust your network accordingly.

This means that you need to come up with a representative set of sample inputs yourself and also decide manually what your network should output for those samples.

The point of training your network is that it should generalize well afterwards so that it can produce quality output for unknown inputs from the real world that weren't present in your training set.